# Grep for one thing then cut from the line below

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, grep

Okay so I can't figure this out. Like a file that I using grep in order to get certain information has it set-up like this.

```
#aaaa
<numbers 123456>

blah
blah
blah

#bbbb
<numbers 2156488>

blah
blah
blah

#cccc
<numbers 5478624>

blah
blah
blah
```

What I am doing is I am greping for `aaaa` or `bbbb` or `cccc` and the information that i really need is the numbers. As in when i grep for `aaaa` the thing i want to obtain is really just the numbers right below it. In this case it would `123456`

I know how to grep for `aaaa` but i don't know how to go to the next line and cut the number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `-C` option of `grep` to show one line of context. Then you can `tail` on the last line (`-n 1`), `cut` using spaces and selecting the second field, `cut` again using `>` and selecting the first field. Thus:

```
$ grep aaaa file -C 1 | tail -n 1 | cut -f2 -d' ' | cut -d'>' -f1
123456
```

will give back the number you're requesting.

The most important part is the `-C` option of `grep`

Comment: That is a GNU `grep` extension.  Since this is tagged Linux, it is fair, but it won't work everywhere.

Comment: You can also use the `-A 1` option for 1 line after the match instead of before and after.

Comment: Yes, but the `tail` is still needed since the match line will still be shown. Thus, no update on the command lenght.

As for the fact that this is a GNU extension, I recognize that I didn't know about it. Since I don't know other `grep`s I'll keep the answer and delete it if the asker tells that this is not what he needs :)

Answer (score 5):

Using sed:

```
sed -n '/aaaa/{
N
s/[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\).*/\1/p
}' input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks more like a job for `sed` to me:

```
sed -n '/^#[a-z]\{4\}/{ N; s/#.*\n<numbers //; s/>//p; }'
```

The `-n` says don't print by default.  The `/^#[a-z]\{4\}/` looks for lines like `#aaaa`; the actions inside `{ ... }` apply only to such lines.  The `N` means 'read the next line'; the first `s///` removes the material before the number; the second removes the trailing `>` and prints.

There are other options on how to do the 'delete irrelevant material', such as just one substitute command: `s/[^0-9]*\([0-9][0-9]+\).*/\1/`; this captures the first string of digits and removes everything else.  It will handle more variations in the input than the more constrained regular expressions originally shown.

Output from sample data:

```
123456
2156488
5478624
```

This isn't automatically a job for `sed`; change it so that the interesting information was the third line after the match and it would be getting fiddly in `sed` (though `N;N;N;` probably does what's wanted).

Comment: Could this also be accomplished with `awk` or is `sed` a quicker/cleaner way?

Comment: It can be done with `awk` using the `getline` function to read the next line when you find the marker line.

Answer (score 0):

@ Lars Kotthoff

Your suggestion to use the `-A 1` option worked perfectly!

The answer using your input is this:

```
grep "aaaa" file -A 1 | grep "<numbers" | cut -d" " -f2 | cut -d">" -f1
```

I would love to give you the credit for this one!

Answer (score 0):

If you are not insisting on `grep`
`+0` to get rid of ">"

```
awk 'f{print $2+0; exit} /^#aaaa/{f=1}' foo.txt
```

Or

```
awk 'f{print $2+0; f=0} /^#aaaa/{f=1}' foo.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
for i in "aaaa bbbb"
do
sed -n '/'"$i"'/,+1 p' test |tail -n1|cut -d' ' -f2| sed 's/.$//'
done
```

Its not very efficient but does the job fine.